# Do a database query on Textbox onblur event

Tags: c#, asp.net-3.5

I am using asp.net 3.5 with C#. I need to do a database lookup when a user enters ProductID in txtProductID. I guess doing javascript is out of the question since this will have to be server side call. 
I wrote this code in the page_load event of the webpage:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtProductID.Attributes.Add("onblur", "LookupProduct()");
    }

        protected void LookupProduct()
    {
        //Lookup Product information on onBlur event;
    }
```

I get an error message: Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
How can I resolve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [TextBox.TextChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textchanged.aspx) event.

ASPX markup:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtProductID" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txtProductID_TextChanged" />
```

Codebehind:

```
protected void txtProductID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // do your database query here
}
```

Comment: Note that this answer will cause PostBack while @durilai's will not.

Answer (score 5):

`onblur` is a client-side event.  `LookupProduct` is a server-side method.  You can't reference one from the other - there's simply no association whatsoever between the two.

There's no quick fix for this - you have to either trigger a postback on the client event (using `ClientScriptManager.GetPostBackEventReference`) or implement an Ajax callback using a library like Microsoft [ASP.NET Ajax](http://www.asp.net/(S(vovsvx454o5rex452c4ypcy3))/ajax/).

Alternatively, if you don't really need to fire this event on every blur, and only when the text has *changed*, then you can simply use the server-side `TextBox.OnChanged` event and set the TextBox's `AutoPostBack` property to `true`.  Make sure you remember to set `AutoPostBack`, otherwise this won't get you anywhere.

Comment: The event needs to be fired on LostFocus / onBlur of the TextBox

Comment: @user279521: There is no server-side `LostFocus` event in ASP.NET, so if you must wire it up to the `onblur` event, then you need to construct the postback/callback as indicated in the second paragraph.

Comment: @user279521. Look at my answer below which will allow you to call a server side method from any type of JavaScript event.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, as referenced here: http://www.codedigest.com/CodeDigest/80-Calling-a-Serverside-Method-from-JavaScript-in-ASP-Net-AJAX---PageMethods.aspx

These are the controls

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" onblur="LookupProduct()" runat="server" />
```

This is the Javascript

```
<script language="javascript">
function LookupProduct()
{  
    PageMethods.LookupProduct('',OnSuccess, OnFailure);
}

function OnSuccess(result) {
    if (result)
    {
    }
}

function OnFailure(error) {
}
</script>
```

This is the server sidewebmethod

```
[WebMethod]
public static bool LookupProduct()
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: ^^ while already using an UpdatePanel, which is a better way to achieve this behaviour, the onTextChanged event handler or your suggested PageMethods way?

Comment: It depends. Do you want a postback? If so then the `ontextchanged` is probably the way to go. I wrote my answer around his markup, while the @jrummel's answer has less code.