# query a database on onblur textbox event asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to query database on onblur event of a textbox.
Simple I want is that when I enter the ID in first textbox and after onblur event occurs, the name of the respective ID from database is shown in another textbox or label.

Comment: can you post your code..what you have tried yet..?

Comment: Which ASP.NET framework do you use ? MVC, WebForms, Web Matrix .etc. ?

Comment: i have not tried practically because i dont have any idea how to do it.. if u have confusion in my question, then let me know, i'll explain it further..

Comment: This link may help you to get started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427740/do-a-database-query-on-textbox-onblur-event

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code, edit this code in your event

```
   var yourParameter = ....; //Your Value from your event , the value of textbox
   var mySelectQuery = ....; //Enter name stored procedure
   var myConnectionString = ....; //Enter string connection

   using(var myConnection = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
   {
   using(var myCommand = new SqlCommand(mySelectQuery, myConnection))
   {
      myConnection.Open();
      myCommand.CommandType =  CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      myCommand.Parameters.Add(
    new SqlParameter("@YourParameter", yourParameter));
      SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
      while(myReader.Read()) 
      {
        Console.WriteLine(myReader.GetString(0));
      }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ontextboxchanged event for this.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged" />

  protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //call the database stored procedure
}
```